# Fast way to get all sub-matrices A[1:mid, (mid+1):n]

Tags: r, matrix, submatrix

Given a matrix `A` of dimension `n x n`, my objective is to get all submatrices `A[1:mid, (mid+1):n]` and convert them as a list of vectors. Here `mid` runs from `1` to `n-1`.

For example, if `A = matrix(1:16, 4, 4)`, then the result will be `res = list(as.vector(A[1:1,2:4]), as.vector(A[1:2,3:4]), as.vector(A[1:3,4:4]))`. A for loop can achieve this but it takes lots of time when `n` is huge.

Comment: `n=nrow(A);lapply(1:(n-1),function(mid) as.vector(A[1:mid, (mid+1):n] ))` ?

Comment: If lapply is not enough maybe you should try with Rcpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function to do it within an apply:

```
solve=function(n,x){
  c(x[1:n,(n+1):dim(x)[2]])
}
sapply(1:3,solve,x=A)
```